# Writing text from a file to a pipe, then writing the contents of the pipe to another text file in c

Tags: c, pipe

So I am trying to read from a file then write each character from that file into the pipe, then reading the pipe data and writing the contents of the pipe to another text file.

The problem I am having is in the second part of the pipe as it reads the data onto the pipe perfectly but when I try to write the pipe data to another file it only writes the first char of the pipe. I know I should set up a loop to go through the chars in the pipe and write the chars one after the other into the text file but I dont understand how to do that. I dont have a great understanding of the read() function and that could be my problem but im not sure.

```
else
{
 close([WRITE_END]);
 read(pfd[READ_END], &c, 1);
 putc(c, from1);
}
```

from1 is my second text file that the chars are wrote to.

I still cant figure out how to use the read() function to print out every char in the pipe. As the chars in the pipe are 'hello1', yet it only writes out 'h'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should do this with two threads or processes, not loops in the same function. Otherwise you will deadlock when you fill the pipe. Then you should read from the pipe the same way you read from a file: read in a loop until `read()` returns `0` to indicate EOF.

Comment: I think you should be showing us an MCVE ([MCVE]).  There are enough problems in the code fragment shown (missing `pfd` before `[WRITE_END]`, no loop, not clear what `from1` is, etc) to make it futile to speculate on what you're doing right and what you're doing wrong.